# Engine swapped my KIA but dont get a spark

Tags: engine, electrical, electronic-control-module, swap, bcm

I engine swapped my KIA optima 2.4L N/A with the 2.0L turbo variant, however when I use the original 2.4L N/A ECU I get spark from the plugs but when I swap the ECU to the 2.0L turbo variant I get no spark.
Am I supposed to match the VIN on the ECU to the car or link the ECU to the BCM?
The ECU for the 2.0L engine was purchased from a different car but is the correct one.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!